# Python database sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I got a little program with my code below:

```
def get_code(hex_pattern, database='./AndroidLockScreenRainbow.sqlite'):
    try:
        if os.path.exists(database):
            with lite.connect(database) as db:
                with db.cursor() as c:
                    c.execute("SELECT * FROM RainbowTable")
                    rows = c.fetchall()
                    for row in rows:
                        if row[0] == hex_pattern:
                            return row[1]
        else:
            raise lite.OperationalError("Database file not exists")
    except lite.OperationalError:
        print('Given SQL table not found!')
```

When the code reach the line with db.cursor() as c:, the program gives the following error

> ```
> with db.cursor() as c:
> AttributeError: __exit__
> ```

What do I wrong?

Comment: The cursor doesn't support a context manager. You cant use `with` with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression passed to the `with` statement (`db.cursor()`) in this case should return a context manager object. A context manager object must have both an `__enter__`and `__exit__` method ( Under the hood, the `with` statement uses these the methods to ensure that the object is cleaned up correctly).

The sqlite3 cursor object doesn't implement these methods so it isn't a valid context manager method, hence the error message you're getting.

You could write your own context manager around cursor. You could write one yourself, but in most cases this isn't necessary, just assign db.cursor() to db directly

```
c = db.cursor()
```